# How to split two titles by line pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

i have the chart and two title names for y axis, how i can split this names by continuous vertical line,    example:

```
Name = [Igorj,borja,vasja]
Surname = [Johson, Cage, Travolta]
```

Title

Name | Surname

Comment: Could you add or link to a picture of what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` the lists together, then iterate over them and `join` them with a `'|'` delimiter. Then use that generated list for your labels.

```
>>> [' | '.join(pair) for pair in zip(Name, Surname)]
['Igorj | Johson', 'borja | Cage', 'vasja | Travolta']
```

Comment: Thank you very much but i need to add continues vertical line from 0 to 10 of "y" axes, if i will use your methon i will have this: _ _ _ _ _ _ _, but i nedd this _____________(but vertical). Thank you